# Creating an index taking ages

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this database with three columns id, hash and name. I have to query this table using where clause on the hash value which is a string. I have already loaded 100 million entries in it. I am trying to create an index using the following command

```
CREATE INDEX i ON table (sequence) using HASH
```

How much time will it take and how much speed up I will gain after having this index. I am using mysql by the way

Comment: you will get a significant performance improvement. what storage engine?

Comment: @SamD My storage engine is MyISAM. How long will it take to query one string using where clause?

Comment: It depends on how complex the query is but for a simple select, less than a second.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing will definitely help.
For better performance on my MYISAM you should take a look at optimizing these variables:

```
key_buffer_size, myisam_max_sort_file_size and 
myisam_sort_buffer_size. key_buffer_size
```

I would recommend using Innodb though.

Comment: Ok I will use Innodb then.

Comment: Then if you do change innodb_buffer_pool_size to 60% of your RAM